# D3 inside for loop not working as expected

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

I have 16 `rect` inside a `svg` element whose id is `photo0`, `photo1`... `photo15`

I want to create mouser over effect for each cell so when user hover over a certain `rect`, it will grab certain picture to populate a photo cell.

However, when I write the `mouserover` one by one, it works perfectly. Like below:

```
d3.select('#photo'+0).on("mouseover", function(d){
        d3.select('#photo').selectAll('img').remove();
        d3.select('#photo').append("img")
                .attr("src","/path/images/" + 0 + ".jpeg" )
                .attr("x", -8)
                .attr("y", -8)
                .attr("width","500px")                  
                .attr("height","500px"); 
});

d3.select('#photo'+1).on("mouseover", function(d){
        d3.select('#photo').selectAll('img').remove();
        d3.select('#photo').append("img")
                .attr("src","/path/images/" + 1 + ".jpeg" )
                .attr("x", -8)
                .attr("y", -8)
                .attr("width","500px")                  
                .attr("height","500px"); 
});

d3.select('#photo'+2).on("mouseover", function(d){
        d3.select('#photo').selectAll('img').remove();
        d3.select('#photo').append("img")
                .attr("src","/path/images/" + 2 + ".jpeg" )
                .attr("x", -8)
                .attr("y", -8)
                .attr("width","500px")                  
                .attr("height","500px"); 
});
...
```

However, when I put them into a for loop, it won't work. And it seems like every cell is calling the last picture somehow, can anyone help?

```
for(i=0;i<16;i++){
d3.select('#photo'+i).on("mouseover", function(d){
        d3.select('#photo').selectAll('img').remove();
        d3.select('#photo').append("img")
                .attr("src","/path/images/" + i + ".jpeg" )
                .attr("x", -8)
                .attr("y", -8)
                .attr("width","500px")                  
                .attr("height","500px"); 
});
}
```

Comment: Declare a function value of your handler, and assign that value to each element in the loop. In your loop, each function is is a closure with 'i' and that's what is making it behave as it is. I can give you a better answer when I have more than my phone in a bit.

Comment: Please provide more detail. If you can offer some pseudo code that will be super helpful.

Comment: ["Creating closure in loops, a common mistake"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Closures#Creating_closures_in_loops.3A_A_common_mistake)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what's happening:

```
for(i=0;i<16;i++){
d3.select('#photo'+i).on("mouseover", function(d){
        d3.select('#photo').selectAll('img').remove();
        d3.select('#photo').append("img")
                .attr("src","/path/images/" + i + ".jpeg" ) // Accesses `i` from closure, 
                                                            // will always be last value
                                                            // that met `i < 16`
                .attr("x", -8)
                .attr("y", -8)
                .attr("width","500px")                  
                .attr("height","500px"); 
});
}
```

What you need is one function value that does what you need, then using that value instead of creating a new function in each iteration. Here is an example (disclaimer, I have never used d3 and this is based on your code):

```
var populateCell = function(i) { 
  d3.select('#photo').selectAll('img').remove(); 
  d3.select('#photo').append('img')
      .attr('src', '/path/images/' + i + '.jpeg')
      .attr('x', -8)
      .attr('y', -8)
      .attr('width', '500px')
      .attr('height', '500px');
};

var selectCell = function(i) { 
  return d3.select('#photo' + i); 
}; 

var i = 0; // explicit definition of `i`
for (; i < 16; i++) { 
  selectCell(i).on('mouseover', populateCell(i)); 
}
```

Here's an example of the unexpected behavior using just JavaScript and assuming `console`, to demonstrate the principle:

```
// Will output 16, 16 times. 

var i = 0; 
var f = [];
for (; i < 16; i++) { 
  f.push(function() { // new function created in each iteration 
    console.log(i);   // captures access to `i`, outputs value of `i` at
                      // at time function is called. 
  });
}

for (var j = 0; j < f.length; j++) { 
  f[j]();
}
```

And an example of desired behavior, with the fixes I commented about.

```
// Will output 0 through 16.  
var i = 0; 
var f = [];
var fn = function(i) { 
  console.log(i);
}

for (; i < 16; i++) { 
  f.push(fn(i));
}

for (var j = 0; j < f.length; j++) { 
  f[j]();
}
```

More information: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Closures